Athena Query not finding the right columns from previous CTE
I have this athena query that start from current date and create  one-day intervals for last 364 days. The intervals section is complaining because DateSeries has only one column "end_date" but Intervals is select 2 columns but they query is just adding a new column using the "end_date"
WITH RECURSIVE DateSeries (end_date) AS (
    SELECT DATE_ADD('day', 1, current_date) AS end_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD('day', -1, end_date)
    FROM DateSeries
    WHERE end_date > DATE_ADD('day', -364, DATE_ADD('day', 1, current_date))
),
Intervals AS (
    SELECT
        end_date,
        DATE_ADD('day', -30, end_date) AS start_date
    FROM DateSeries
),

I have tried a lot of things but I am at lost. Does anyone know where I need to make adjustments to get this working?
As result, I expect a list of 2 columns [start_date, end_date] that are one day apart.

With the Intervals CTE you have to add column aliases and then you would tweak the DATE_ADD from -30 to 1
Something like (comments added):
WITH RECURSIVE DateSeries(end_date) AS (
    SELECT DATE_ADD('day', 1, current_date) AS end_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_ADD('day', -1, dt.end_date) as end_date
    FROM DateSeries dt
    WHERE dt.end_date > DATE_ADD('day', -365, DATE_ADD('day', 1, current_date))
),
Intervals (state_date, end_date) as ( --This line you have to add the columns (state_date, end_date)
    SELECT dt.end_date,
        DATE_ADD('day', 1, dt.end_date) AS start_date --here you would change -30 to 1 to get a start_date and end_date 1 day apart
    FROM DateSeries dt
)
select *
from Intervals

Problem is with Athena that would throw an error as recursive CTE can only be 10 deep:

That is called out in their SELECT documentation.
In the DateSeries CTE you can change the -365 to -10 and it would work but I speculate you need a full year of date ranges.
If all you are building or needing is basically a calendar table with a start date and end date 1 day apart for the last year just do something like:
with num_table as(
    SELECT *
    FROM UNNEST(sequence(1, 365, 1)) AS t(number)
),
Intervals as (
    select DATE_ADD('day', -366+number, current_date) as start_date,
        DATE_ADD('day', -365+number, current_date) as end_date
    from num_table
)
select *
from Intervals

Which would give results of:

In the num_table CTE

sequence(1, 365, 1) - creates an array of 365 values 1 number apart
doing UNNEST(sequence(1, 365, 1)) - takes the array and gives you a row for each of the numbers

Then we just do date functions to get our start and end dates.
Might have to adjust for your specific use case.
